Code Run time Measurement on a LPC55s69 Development Board
I am working with LPC55s69 development board and i want to calculate the amount of time it requires to run a simple "Hello World" program. How can I do it? I am a beginner at this and this is also my first time working with the development board.

Your toolchain's debugger may be able to do that directly.  But what you measuring?  Just the execution of printf or the time from reset to termination of main()?  The result will be dominated by the run-time start-up initialisation, and may be misleading if you are not clear about what you are measuring and how.

Benchmarking stdio.h functions is pretty meaningless on MCU applications. You shouldn't be using that header for anything but debugging at most.

The most simple solution uses a single port pin and an oscilloscope to measure. Add code to initialize this pin as output and set it where your program begins, and reset it where your program ends.
Then use the oscilloscope to measure the interval. You will notice that there is an additional time after the end of the reset signal and the start of your program.
Please note that you should not return from main() in an embedded system. Where should it return to? If your environment (the C++ runtime provided) is done well, it will run into an endless loop when main() returns. But don't do this unless it is explicitly documented. Commonly you insert an endless loop yourself.
